# redirect to page and anchor using ChaplinJs

Tags: backbone.js, hyperlink, chaplinjs

I have a page `/hello` where i have a link:

```
<a href="{{#url 'goodbye' }}{{/url}}">
```

that will redirect to `/goodbye`. But i want it to use an anchor too, something like `/goodbye#message`

I have tried doing:

```
<a href="{{#url 'goodbye' }}{{/url}}#message">
```

but when I click on it, it will redirect the page to `/goodbye`. It seems like Chaplin is deleting the anchor.

**EDIT:**
For the templates I'm using handlebars (with the chapling boilerplate), the `{{#url}}` helper generates correctly the link ( cf [view-helper.js](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin-boilerplate/blob/master/js/lib/view-helper.js) ). In the rendered page i see:

```
<a href="/goodbye#message">
```

but when i click on it, it just redirects me to `/goodbye`

Any idea?

Comment: What is `{{#url...`? Is that a handlebars helper that comes with Chaplin?

Comment: ah yeap... forgot to specify that.. i'll add it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, I needed to stop the routing on the link. I just added the class `noscript` on the tag

```
<a href="{{#url 'goodbye' }}{{/url}}#message" class="noscript">
```

I couln't find a different way to do it. Hope this helps someone else

cf : [skipRounting on Chaplin.Layout](http://docs.chaplinjs.org/chaplin.layout.html)